# How to go about writing a firefox plugin for an existing cgi script?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I have a cgi script which takes form input, I want to facilitate the use case where if you right click from firefox inputs are passed to the cgi (rather than users entering values explcitly). Firstly can this be done? If yes any pointers where I can start/snippets of code where I can look would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done. Google for firefox extension and you'll get lots of pointers:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension

http://lifehacker.com/software/programming/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension-264490.php

Since most extensions don't contain any compiled code (most of it will be xml (xul) and javascript) you can also look for an extension that does part of what you want and investigate it's contents -- be sure to check the license before you start copying the (complete) code however. Adding "right click" to your google search might help you to find those.